# PDF and other printers don't show in printer list in Quasar Accounting

Tags: printing, pdf

I am using Xubuntu 20.04 and I'm having some difficulty with some features for the PDF and Canon printers.

The issue is, I installed the printers and they work well to print from the browser and elsewhere but they do not show up in the printer list inside of Quasar Accounting. It only shows my Brother printer and I have 3 printers installed, PDF cups included but only the brother printer shows. The PDF nor the Canon printer shows up on the list. In 18.04 distro, I could see everything that showed in "Printers" folder.

Can anybody help me with this? What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
**Quasar Accounting** - ***An Accounting software developed by Linux Canada Inc. I guess somewhat similar to Quick Books but Open Source.***

Comment: I think this might be a question for the people that made the accounting software,

Comment: Okay. I thought so.Thanks David.